# Debian user desktop not working on TightVnc

Tags: linux, debian, beagleboard

I have a BBB with tighvncserver on it. Iam trying to connect from my windows pc via tightvnc to the beagleboard.

With root its working fine. The desktop displays correctly. See attached Screenshot [image]

But the desktop ob the debian user is not working properly. See attached Screenshot[image]

Why is that? Do anyone of you has a idea and can help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to do the following:

```
chmod +x home/debian/xstartup
```

This will add special execution permission.